# Custom parse JSON fields with GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have following `json`:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Title blabla",
    "thing": {
        "field1": 1,
        "field2": "field2",
        "etc": "etc.."
    }
}
```

and model

```
public class MyModel {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String thing;
}
```

I parse it with `gson`

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 MyModel myModel = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

and want achieve result:

```
myModel.id -> 1
myModel.title -> "Title blabla"
myModel.thing-> "{
              "field1": 1,
              "field2": "field2",
              "etc": "etc.."
             }"
```

In other words I do not want some fields to be deserialized, but left as the original coresponding `json` strings.

How to achieve this using `gson`?

Comment: Have you tried setting 'thing' type to String? If it does not help then you will have to write your own deserializer

Comment: yeah, I try and get runtime error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change String to Object so that it de-/serializes to the same JSON String. Could look like that:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Answers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{" 
                + "    \"id\": 1,"
                + "    \"title\": \"Title blabla\"," + "    \"thing\": {"
                + "        \"field1\": 1," + "        \"field2\": \"field2\","
                + "        \"etc\": \"etc..\"" + "    }" 
                + "}";
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        MyModel myModel = (MyModel) gson.fromJson(json, MyModel.class);
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(myModel));

    }

    class MyModel {
        private int id;
        private String title;
        private Object thing;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
{"id":1,"title":"Title blabla","thing":{"field1":1.0,"field2":"field2","etc":"etc.."}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could change thing to a Map and then toString() that to produce the results you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement your own serializer and desirializer, see [here](http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-google-json-custom-serializer-deserializer.jsp) for example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an inner class if you want to parse a similar JSON object, try this for example :

```
public class MyModel {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String thing;
     public static class thing
     {
     private string field1;
     private string field2;
     etc etc
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't know which fields can be in inner class, thing does't have a permanent structure